# Error installing Caffe on Ubuntu - CPU only

Tags: ubuntu, compiler-errors, installation, caffe, pycaffe

I followed the instructions for installing Caffe on Ubuntu without using the GPU:
﻿https://stackoverflow.com/a/31396229/3198732

The "make all" command finished successfully.
I get the following error when running "make test":

CXX/LD -o .build_release/test/test_all.testbin src/caffe/test/test_caffe_main.cpp
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libcaffe.a(common.o): undefined reference to symbol '_ZN6google21ParseCommandLineFlagsEPiPPPcb'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgflags.so: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [.build_release/test/test_all.testbin] Error 1

Any idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

you need to install gflags.
Follow this link https://github.com/google/python-gflags