# Caffe multi CPU build

Tags: multithreading, build, multiprocessing, caffe

I'm trying to build [Caffe](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe) on Ubuntu 14.04 x64 in VirtualBox with openblas in CPU_ONLY mode.([Enviroment install script](https://github.com/mrgloom/Caffe-snippets/blob/master/Virtualbox_Ubuntu_14.04_CPU.sh) , [Makefile.config](https://github.com/mrgloom/Caffe-snippets/blob/master/Makefile.config) )

Also I'm not compiling [OpenBlas](https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS), but install it via `apt-get` like `sudo apt-get -y install libopenblas-dev`, can it be reason of the problem?

After I set any of this variables, there is no speed improvement and in `htop` I see only one CPU utilisation.

```
export OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=4
export GOTO_NUM_THREADS=4
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=4
```

How to check if Caffe use several threads / CPUs?

**UPDATE:**

I tried caffe binary on [MNIST example](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/gathered/examples/mnist.html) and it utilise 400% of CPU.

1 thread

```
I0520 15:58:09.749832 12424 caffe.cpp:178] Use CPU.
...
I0520 16:06:14.553506 12424 caffe.cpp:222] Optimization Done.
~8 min
```

4 threads

```
I0520 16:06:44.634735 12446 caffe.cpp:178] Use CPU.
...
I0520 16:13:15.904394 12446 caffe.cpp:222] Optimization Done.
~6.5 min
```

`ps -T -p <PID>` gives me:

`export OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=1`
 6 threads

`export OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=4`
 9 threads

Seems openblas works, but it depends on network architecture?

Also seems [Caffe also use BLAS for conv layers](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/convolution.html).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the intel branch on CentOS 7.3 and able to see 2500% CPU usage on my Broadwell when training caffenet example. The following is the steps I used to build the tools:

```
git clone https://github.com/BVLC/caffe.git caffe_intel
cd caffe_intel
git branch -r
git checkout intel
cp Makefile.config.example Makefile.config
  # mkl will be automatically download once make is run
  # Edit Makefile.config in the following lines
  PYTHON_LIB := /usr/lib64
  LIBRARY_DIRS := $(PYTHON_LIB) /usr/local/lib /usr/lib64 /usr/lib   
yum install cmake # will be used to build mkl as a sub-routine of make
make -j32 all
make pycaffe
make distribute
cd distribute/lib
ln -s ../../external/mkldnn/install/lib/libmkldnn.so .
```

And put caffe_intel/distribute/bin in $PATH, caffe_intel/distribute/lib in $LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Also, enable mkl library by adding the following line at the beginning of prototxt file(s)

```
engine: "MKL2017"
```